# How to correctly feed type argument in this toy theorem?

Tags: coq

I have a recursive function **combine** defined as following:

```
Fixpoint combine {X Y : Type} (lx : list X) (ly : list Y)
           : list (X*Y) :=
  match lx, ly with
  | [], _ => []
  | _, [] => []
  | x :: tx, y :: ty => (x, y) :: (combine tx ty)
  end.
```

Where list is defined as:

```
Inductive list (X:Type) : Type :=
  | nil
  | cons (x : X) (l : list X).
```

then I tried to define a lemma that looks like this:

```
Lemma list_nil_imply_combine_nil: forall {X: Type} (l: list X), 
  l = [] -> combine l [] = [].
```

but when executing the Lemma definition, Output says:

```
Cannot infer the implicit parameter Y of combine whose type is 
"Type" in environment:
X : Type
l : list X
```

I'm not sure **how to correctly feed type arguments to [] i.e. nil constructor.**. Any hint or direction for help material is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should your lemma rather read:

```
Lemma list_nil_imply_combine_nil: forall {X Y: Type} (l: list X), 
  combine l ([] : list Y) = [].
```

?

Anyway, a solution is to explicitly give the type of `[]`, which is enough to help Coq find the type argument by itself:

```
Lemma list_nil_imply_combine_nil: forall {X Y: Type} (l: list X), 
  combine l ([] : list Y) = [].
```

Another is to feed the argument yourself, like so:

```
Lemma list_nil_imply_combine_nil: forall {X Y: Type} (l: list X), 
  combine l (@nil Y) = [].
```

The use of `@` locally deactivates the implicit arguments, letting you give *all* arguments.

Answer (score 2):

you need to type the nil :

```ml
Lemma list_nil_imply_combine_nil: forall {X Y : Type} (l: list X), 
  l = [] -> combine l ([] : list Y) = [].
```